# Delphi memory management with XML interfaces and types

Tags: xml, delphi, interface

I have an old app (started in Delphi 2007) where I've recently noticed lots of memory leaks. A lot of these occur in a configuration module that uses an XML config file. I have a hierarchy of interfaces and classes that were generated by Delphi 2007's "XML Data Binding" tool. Basically, I have a bunch of interfaces and classes like the following:

```
IXMLMyObject = interface(IXMLNode) // Or things like IXMLNodeCollection, etc.
    [GUID]
    function GetMyField: Integer;
    procedure SetMyField(value: Integer);
    property MyField: Integer read GetMyField write SetMyField;
end;

TXMLMyObject = class(TXMLNode, IXMLMyObject)
    function GetMyField: Integer;
    procedure SetMyField(value: Integer);
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;  // If needed
```

Now there is a whole hierarchy of these interfaces/classes. Ultimately, the config file is read with something like the following:

```
function GetSettings(Doc: IXMLDocument): IXMLMyObject;
begin
  Result := Doc.GetDocBinding('MyObject', TXMLMyObject, TargetNamespace) as IXMLMyObject;
end;

function LoadMyObjectFromFile(const FileName: WideString): IXMLDocument;
begin
  Result := LoadXMLDocument(FileName);
end;
```

I load the XML settings with one of these last two files, and then can pass portions of the settings to various Delphi classes, using the IXMLMyClass "pointers". The problem I'm having is I don't really know how to deal with memory deallocation. I think I am hopelessly confused between various Windows concepts (COM, etc.) and Delphi's concept of interfaces. It's hard to believe I've managed a great deal of sanity over the past 13 years with this code, especially since:

1. I'm the sole developer
2. This has been a part-time endeavor (one day per week, at most, with month-long gaps)
3. Over the years, I've used Delphi 2007, XE7, and most recently, 10.2
4. I am primarily an embedded developer, and since I started this back in 2007, I have continually moved further towards Linux and RTOS systems, and away from Windows.

At this point, I am so confused as to when/where Delphi does memory management for me, or when I am responsible for it myself. Tonight, I found what appears to be a leak, but when I try something like this:

`if Assigned(FSomeXMLObject) then FreeAndNil(FSomeXMLObject);`

I get exceptions, but if I do this:

`FSomeXMLObject := nil;`

I get memory leaks.

I realize this is a long, rambling question, and given I've been at this for so many years, I should be able to ask better questions, it's quite embarrassing to write this post. I've just never been able to wrap my head around when memory is allocated/disposed for me with IXMLNode objects, nor really how to deal with IXMLNode properly. This 13-year project has rather suddenly become hugely unstable, so much that I am at a loss as to where to begin. It seems some fundamental understanding has eluded me for so long, tempting me along, and now has decided to pull the rug out from under me!

I am asking for help, but I don't really know how to say what exactly is my problem; my only hope is someone has been in a similar situation and can point me to a reference or two to get me out of this quagmire in which I am stuck.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of a leak happening

Comment: See [Memory Management of Interface Objects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Memory_Management_of_Interface_Objects)

Answer (score 3):

> The problem I'm having is I don't really know how to deal with memory deallocation.

As long as you [follow the rules for proper interface usage](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Interfaces), you don't need to worry about deallocating anything manually.  Interfaces are reference counted, and Delphi will handle the refcounts automatically for you.  When an interface variable is assigned to, its refcount is incremented automatically.  When an interface variable is assigned `nil` or goes out of scope, its refcount is decremented automatically.  The object behind the interface is destroyed when its refcount falls to 0.

If you have memory leaks, you are likely doing something wrong to mismanage the refcounts, such as creating an interfaced object directly in a `const` function parameter, or creating strong circular references between your interfaced objects, etc.  How would you know exactly if you have leaks?  Are you looking at a leak report from the RTL's MemoryManager?  If so, please provide that report.  Otherwise, are you just relying on Windows' Task Manager to look at memory usage over time?  That won't show you real leaks, as Task Manager doesn't know how the RTL's Memory Manager uses (and reuses!) memory, so only the Memory Manager can tell you what is really a leak and what is not a leak.

We can't see what your code is actually doing, so we can't see if it is leaking or not.  The code you have shown is fine as-is, so the leaks (if they exist) have to be in code you have not shown yet.

Comment: Thanks for the references Remy and Ken, and I do apologize for the rambling question - it was late and I was tired and frustrated - never a good time to write a SO Question! I know I have memory leaks from madExcept. It would be very difficult to pull out a minimal example. However, the references you both provided, along with the minimal example, have inspired me to write a new, small program whereby I hope to demonstrate the leaks and understand things better. This may also serve as a minimal example; if it works out that way, I'll post it here.

Comment: @Bob "*I know I have memory leaks from madExcept*" - then it should also be telling you *where* those leaks are actually occurring, so you can go review that code to determine *why* it is leaking.

Comment: Yes, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to find them. The current bug seems to be after a FormClose is complete, and all the stack entries are Delphi RTL calls - none of mine - so I don't know how to track it down to my code, which is surely at fault here.

Comment: @Bob Leak reports should be telling you where the leaked memory is being allocated from. Surely that lead you to some sections of your code? If the leaks are not in your own code, then you shouldn't be worrying about them. Are you compiling with Debug DCUs turned on so you can step through the RTL's source code with the debugger?